# spree_i18n integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm, bundler, spree

I'm trying to get the spree_i18n gem working, but am not quite getting it.

I've added this to the Gemfile:
gem 'spree_i18n', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree_i18n.git'
I'm using RVM, so bundle installed it to:
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@spree/bundler/gems/spree_i18n-e5e3e189c843
instead of the usual location at:
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@spree/gems/
so I'm not sure if RVM is doing something weird.

But running any of the  rake spree_i18n:xxx commands results in the following error:
'Don't know how to build task 'spree_i18n:new'

I'm guessing it's because the gem isn't getting picked up by rake and the app.  I was thinking that the app should have picked up on the .yml translation files from the gem folder so I would not need to copy them over to the main app folder.

As a quick fix, I copied over the .yml files from the gem folder to the app config/locales folder.  It works but definitely feels like a hack.

Can someone please point me in the right direction to integrate this gem correctly?

I've also posted the question here, in case, there's additional information that might help to solve this.
https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/spree-user/6ycWGfm6eTk

Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Gady It was most likely user error, but it worked fine on another project so I didn't find out what exactly it was.  The discussion on Google Groups, linked in the question, is still ongoing...periodically.

Answer (score 0):

see related closed issue on github

https://github.com/spree/spree_i18n/issues/171